# jQuery Hover not work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery

I have the HTML code:

```
<span style="padding-right:100px;" class="tree_list">
    <p>Hover Here</p>
    <span class="admin_tools" id="tree_list_tool">
        <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

The CSS code:

```
.admin_tools {
     display:none;
}
```

And the jQuery code to execute:

```
$('.tree_list').hover(
    function(){
         $('#tree_list_tool', $(this)).show();
    } ,
    function(){
         $('#tree_list_tool', $(this)).hide();
    }
);
```

The jQuery hover function works well on Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome and Safari. I have searched on Google but no the result. Could you give me some solutions ?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Duplicate Question, try searching before you post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221276/jquery-hover-not-working-in-safari-or-chrome

Comment: @Sudhir: Actually I have read that post but it didn't help me solve my problem so I create this post. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wLZx5/1/) (except for the fact that in the code you have provide there isn't anything to "hover" over) I suspect that there is more to this story...

ps: you really don't need a context if you're targeting an ID `$('#tree_list_tool', $(this))` ;)